# Ionic setting up a global variable

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, global-variables

Let say I have multilevel objects in Ionic project:

```
getData() {
    this.http.get(this.url)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(data => {
        this.data = data;
        console.log(data);                  
    });
};
```

Then I get multiple objects

```
[Objects,Objects,Objects,Objects,Objects,...]
```

which looks like below...

```
0:Objects
  0: 'Something'
  1: 'Else'
  ...
1:Objects
  0: 'Name'
  1: 'What?'
  ...
2:Objects
  0: 'This'
  1: 'That'
  ...
```

I searched around in Ionic forums and other sites about setting up a global variable.

Basically, I need to access this variable from various pages and I thought instead of sending certain data as parameters, I will simply access them when necessary.

How would I achieve this?

Comment: You can create a service which exposed an Observable for this global data. then when the service is initialized you make the http request and publish new data in the observable (using the next method), then every page which needs this data can inject the service and subscribe for new data of the service's observable

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I think I understand most of them. Do you happen to know an example of it? Thanks.